# What does this code mean? (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I am reading a plugin and can understand this part

```
$('<ul />', {
    'class': settings.ulClass,
    html: albumItem.join('')
}).appendTo($this);
```

1. What is this html: `albumItem.join('')`. Is `html` a keyword or user defined? I can't search because any word with `html` return too generic result
2. Is this a selection similar to this `$('p').appendto($this)` ? If so where can I search the grammar of this?

Thanks

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes for the documentation of the jQuery notation being used to create the `ul` element.

Answer (score 4):

[.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is a native method of Array objects, it Joins all elements of an array into a string.

Assuming `albumItem` is an array, `albumItem.join('')` will join all the elements in the array to create a string where the joining character is an empty string.

Ex:

```
var albumItem = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
albumItem.join('') // will give 'onetwothree'
```

Your code

```
$('<ul />', {
            'class': settings.ulClass,
            html: albumItem.join('')
        }).appendTo($this);
```

will create a `ul` element with class returned by `settings.ulClass` and will have the contents of the array `albumItem` as children and this element will get appended to the element referenced by `$this`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/am7hk/1/)